# hg convert not actually converting?

Tags: mercurial, perforce, mercurial-convert

I run the following hg command and see a whole bunch of revision numbers & their messages fly past my screen, but when it finishes the destination hg repository is empty.

hg convert -s p4 //depot/proj1/... c:\hg\proj1 --config convert.p4.startrev=1267

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out my Perforce database had a bit of corruption in very early changesets. Once I told the convert extension to start at a later change set, the conversion went without a hitch.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, **use the summary command**. You'll probably see something like this:

```
$ hg sum
parent: -1:000000000000  (no revision checked out)
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: 15225 new changesets (update)
```

This says "nothing checked out, on the default branch, nothing to commit, 15225 changesets if you update".

An *empty* repo looks like this:

```
$ hg sum
parent: -1:000000000000 tip (empty repository)
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
```

Answer (score 2):

The repository is not empty. There should be an empty directory, `.hg`, which contains the whole history of your project.

If you want to see the state of your repo at the latest revision, you can update your local copy with `hg update`.